# How can I find the daily hirsute hippo?

Tags: updates, 21.04, tar, release-management, daily-build

Here is the [ubuntu base](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/):

- bionic/
- daily (impish indri)/
- focal/
- releases/

for example: this is daily [focal](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/focal/daily/current/)

As you can see, there is no daily Hirsute Hippo.
How can I find the daily hirsute hippo (tar.gz format, which might be around 23 to 25 MB)?

Answer (score 5):

Dailies are for pre-release testing. After release, there is no more daily respin.

- The final release for 21.04 is at https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/releases/21.04/.
- There are dailies for LTS releases (Bionic/18.04 and Focal/20.04) because there are still point releases being tested.

WARNING: Ubuntu-base does not include an installer or a kernel. It takes skill to install (manually) properly. It is not for beginners.

Comment: I want the update version of hirsute hippo, the current version has an update problem، When I upgrade, it hang.

Comment: That's why I have to install focal over and over again. Because Indri is also completely unstable.

Comment: Oh. Seems like a classic [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You didn't ask about your "update problem". You asked about your favorite solution (new 21.04 dailies). Open a new question detailing your "update problem"

Comment: That question may have already been asked before,  Although the link you provided was helpful. For another problem I have lol!, thanks for that.

Comment: If you are finding pre-release 21.10 to be "completely unstable", then please report it's failures in the proper venues. Now is the time: Ubuntu developers are focused on squashing 21.10 bugs and making it stable and reliable right now. After release is too late.

Comment: that topic (Impish indri) is also off topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 21.04 (*hirsute hippo*) has been released, so no more dailies are produced.

You can find mention of dailies here - http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/ but you'll note they report as "*Released*".

For LTS releases, there are later *point* releases, eg. [Ubuntu 20.04.3 has just been released](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/) but *dailies* will exist for *focal* as the next release will be 20.04.4, which will contain all patches between now and the 20.04.4 release, plus the kernel stack from Ubuntu 21.10 (currently *impish indri*) as well.

Comment: But that version is from several months ago. 2021-04-20

Comment: The versions in the ISO QA (Quality Assurance) tracker will of course be prior to release; ie. they'll contain the last RC (Release Candidate), the release details can be found many places including https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/04/22/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-released/ ie. released on (Thu Apr 22 17:02:00 UTC 2021*.    Dailies are produced to ensure the product is good before release (ie. for Quality Assurance purposes).

Comment: Also note "daily" really means interval; at times in the cycle a *daily* can be produced once per week; other times it's multiple times per day, even if most of the cycle they are produced once per day (hence the name).  Once they reach RC (release candidate) they are produced only on demand

Comment: In my opinion, it is necessary to include hirsute hipppo's daily release، For professional purposes.